# Why is rewind() not working as expected in this simple program?

Tags: c, text-files, filestream, getc, rewind

Why is the below program not printing the first character of the newly created text file (**"E"**) as expected? It's a simple program and I tried to look at the issue from all aspects but couldn't find the reason. The text file is being created on my D drive with the content "**EFGHI**", but for some reason **"E"** is not being read even if I rewind and read using `getc()` and the output is **-1**.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int x;
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("F:\\demo.txt","w");
    if(fp==NULL)
        puts("Write error");
    fputs("EFGHI",fp);
    rewind(fp);

    x=getc(fp);
    printf("%d",x);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

**UPDATED:**

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>

    int main()
    {
        int x;
        FILE *fp;
        fp=fopen("F:\\demo.txt","w+");
        if(fp==NULL)
        {
            puts("Write error");
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
        fputs("EFGHI",fp);
        rewind(fp);

        while(!feof(fp))
        {
            x=getc(fp);
            printf("%d\n",x);
        }
        fclose(fp);
     }
```

Comment: You have opened the file for writing only.

Comment: @MOehm Can you also look at the comment I have left under Almo's answer in relation to the update to my code?

Comment: The edit  seems to be a answer to the problem, rather then an update to the question.   If indeed an answer, post the answer below and revert the question to a former state.  If is another question, post a new question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

File mode `"w"` opens the file for writing *only*.

Use `"w+"` to open a file for writing *and* reading.

(Please see [`man fopen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) for more file modes.)

---

Regarding `getc()` returning `-1`, verbatim from [`man getc`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html):

> [...] **getc()** [...] return[s] the character read as an `unsigned char` cast to an `int` or **EOF** on end of file or error.

`EOF` typically equals `-1`. To test this do a `printf("EOF=%d\n", EOF);`

Comment: What does `-1` mean, `EOF`?

Comment: @alk Can you explain why my updated code is printing an additional 6th number -1? (Rest 5 are working as expected: ASCII of E-I)

Comment: @alk Please ignore my last comment. I got what's happening. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 4):

`fp=fopen("F:\\demo.txt","w");`

Opens the file for writing, then you try to read from it. That's not going to work.

I'll also note that your program keeps trying to use `fp` even if it fails to be created since your `if` checking `fp` only prints an error, it doesn't stop the program.

Comment: I updated the code and it's working fine except that it's printing an unexpected 6th number "-1". Can you explain why? Isn't the position pointer expected to encounter EOF after reading 5th character thereby causing the while loop to exit?

Comment: My guess is that `while(!feof(fp))` checks the last character read. So when you hit EOF with `x=getc(fp);`, you print it first, then the while exits.

Comment: Please ignore my last comment. I got what's happening.